# How to sign out of Flask app when signed out of Google first (using "Sign in with Google")

Tags: flask, oauth-2.0, google-signin

I have a Flask app. I've set up [Sign in with Google](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/overview) successfully, according to the docs.

I perform all actions on the server, namely whether the sign-in was successful. If it passes the checks from Google, I check if the user exists in my database and only then do I call `login_user()`

My logout route is simple; it just calls `logout_user()` and deletes the session.

#### But is it possible to detect when the user has signed out of Google first?

Flow:

1. User logs in via Google
2. User has another tab open, say Gmail, and logs out of Google
3. User returns to my app
4. User clicks on a link leading to a **protected** route
5. Server detects user is not logged into Google, so denies the request